# Visual studio emulator android setup block

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator

I'm trying to install the visual studio emulator for android to see my app, but I'm running into the following error.

My laptop is also running on a 64-bit OS.

Also, Xamarin is up to date inside visual studio and I'm using visual studio 2015.

Is there a workaround for this as my windows 8.1 is not the enterprise edition.

Thank you

[image: Blocked]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is quite clear, you need a 64-bit version of Window 8/8.1 or 10 with the Pro or Enterprise edition and also Hyper-V support. There is no workaround to use the `Visual Studio Emulator` without those requirements.

However, you are not limited to the `Visual Studio Emulator`. You can always use the standard Android emulators.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. What I had to do was enable Hyper-V and also change the setting in my bios to enable Virtualization Technology. In my case I had to enable Intel Virtualization Technology, but I think it would be called something different if you are using an AMD processor. After I did those two things, I was able to install the Emulator for Android.